# Kentico 9 form fields.. Is there a way to make a feild into a currency field only?

Tags: forms, kentico

Have a form I am trying to build and even though I have a text box field that will work for users to enter a $ amount it would be nice to make it so that field only accepts numbers and keeps it in the $0.00 format. Seems like a simple thing but I cannot seem to find out how this would be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup you control as followed

- make the **Data type** a **decimal number**
  in the **Editing control settings** click to show the **Advanced** section
- in Filter set **Type** to **Numbers** and **Custom**
- Add **Valid characters** your delimiter (, or .)
- In the **validation** section add a rule for the minimum value to be 0.

The data type will enforce it to be a actual number.

You could also use as **Validation** a **Regular expression** setting something like:

```
^[$]?([0-9]{1,2})?,?([0-9]{3})?,?([0-9]{3})?(\.[0-9]{2})?[$]?$
```

which will allow a dollar sign prefix or suffix.

Comment: Although this is a great conversion and answer Taun Brown, you won't want to store the value with any kind of prefix or suffix to the amount.  This is not standard practice at all and you will essentially break all of the API calls with your string value being stored in the database vs. a numeric value which can then be formatted using simple API calls.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the field as a decimal or double and define the precision (depending on what version you are using).  The field should NOT be a text field but can use a textbox as the displaying control.

From an output standpoint, it will not automatically output $0.00, you have to format that based on the culture.  There are several macros and functions within the API to do this.